# DropDownListFor not rendering unique names

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an MVC page several child action calls to my DropdownListController.  The controller renders  generic partial page with dropdown fields in my form.  The partial page is listed below. The problem is tthat the he Html.DropdownListFor always generates the dropdowns with "SelectedItem" as the name even I specified the name in the HtmlAttribute parameter.  How do I get this unique dropdown name for each child action call to the DropdownListController? In addition, the ValidateionMessageFor doesn't show either when the a value must be selected.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.DropDownListViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.Items, Model.Label, new { id=Model.ElementName, name = Model.ElementName})

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ElementName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownListFor directive sets m.SelectedItem as the control's name + id. So why can't you just use the following?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ElementName, Model.Items, Model.Label)
```